# How to serialize as Json an object structure with circular references?

Tags: c#, json, wcf, serialization

I have an object structure like this:

```
public class Proposal {
    public List<ProposalLine> Lines { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class ProposalLine {
    public Proposal Proposal { get; set; }  // <- Reference to parent object
}
```

I try to serialize Proposal as Json, it tells me that there is a circular reference, which is correct.
Unfortunately, I can't touch the objects, since they are in a referenced DLL from another project - otherwise I'd change them.

Is there a way to serialize as Json and ignore the circular properties?

Comment: You can try [JSon.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) which supports circular references.

Comment: If you want ignore circular references, you should set `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` (see: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_ReferenceLoopHandling.htm)

Answer (score 8):

Use the Newtonsoft.Json (which is the default .net json serializer) and set

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
};
var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);
```

You can also globally define this variable if you are developing MVC applications...

Comment: Although it's a commonly used serialization library (for good reasons) it is not the default. Microsoft has 2 JSON serializers you can use as well.

Comment: In WCF projects the default is DataContractJsonSerializer.

Comment: MS does indeed use multiple serializers.  Newtonsoft is used on the Web API but not on the older Controllers.