# EntityFrameworks, Linq and an optional child

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I have three classes, called Authors, Books and Publishers

An Author can have many Book.
A Book can have many Authors.
A Book can have one  (optional) Publisher.
A Publisher can have many Books.

I want to deliver a collection of authors, books and publishers using WebAPI. I initially had a problem with JSON.Net throwing a Circular Reference exception because of the link back from the Book to the Author.

To get around this I rebuild the List returned from the repository using this:

```
            List<Author> result = data.Select(x => new Author
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            Books = x.Book.Select(y => new Book
            {
                Id = y.Id,
                Name = y.Name,
                Publisher = new Publisher
                {   Id=y.Publisher.Id,
                    Name=y.Publisher.Name,
                }
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

However, I'm running into a problem when a publisher doesn't exist. How do I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Did you try to resolve a problem with circular reference first? Check [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818386/how-to-serialize-as-json-an-object-structure-with-circular-references) answer for configuring JSON serializer to deal with circular references.

Comment: Thank you. I spent ages trying to solve the circular reference issue yesterday. My google skills failed me on finding the Json Serializer fix.