# Exception from Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization

Tags: asp.net, hangfire

I'm integrating Hangfire to my project. I got an exception from Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization in BackgroundJob.Enqueue as below. Can anyone tell me how to troubleshoot this problem?

> Self referencing loop detected for property 'ApplicationInstance' with type 'ASP.global_asax'. Path 'NamingContainer.Page.ModelBindingExecutionContext.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context'.
>
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonProperty property, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, Type type, Formatting formatting, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
>      at Hangfire.Common.Job.GetArguments(MethodCallExpression callExpression)
>      at Hangfire.Common.Job.FromExpression(Expression`1 methodCall)
>      at Hangfire.BackgroundJobClientExtensions.Create(IBackgroundJobClient client, Expression`1 methodCall, IState state)
>      at Hangfire.BackgroundJobClientExtensions.Enqueue(IBackgroundJobClient client, Expression`1 methodCall)
>      at Hangfire.BackgroundJob.Enqueue(Expression`1 methodCall)

Comment: You should use JsonSerializerSettings.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error (not related to Hangfire) because I had a controller method:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyAction(...)
```

and I was returning an `ActionResult` wrapped in another `ActionResult`, like so:

```
return Ok(await Get(Id));
```

... where `Get(Id)` was another action on the controller.

I changed the return statement to:

```
return await Get(Id);
```

And it fixes the issue. The `ApplicationInstance` property mentioned in the error is the hint I needed: the controller is not serializing my POCO entity from the `Get` method; it's serializing the IHttpActionResult that contains that POCO!

Answer (score 0):

You are serializing an object with a property called "ApplicationInstance" that contains a reference to itself.  Mark this property as not serializable.

[How to serialize as Json an object structure with circular references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818386/how-to-serialize-as-json-an-object-structure-with-circular-references) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem came from a parameter which is not serialized. Now I resolved my problem. everything run well. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when calling Post from Fiddler with json in the body.
I finally realized the solution. I hadn't set the content-type in the header. Once I set Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8, the problem disappeared.