# What input will cause golang's json.Marshal to return an error?

Tags: json, go, marshalling

From the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal):

> JSON cannot represent cyclic data structures and Marshal does not handle them. Passing cyclic structures to Marshal will result in an infinite recursion.

I've experienced this situation, which results in a runtime panic.

What I'm wondering is if anyone can provide a working program that demonstrates a non-panic situation where json.Marshal returns a non-nil error. The best answers would **clearly include the inputs used**.

Comment: I'd recommend revising your question slightly because I believe you're looking for a feature like `PreserveReferencesHandling` in newtonsoft's json.NET library (C#) however, I could correctly answer your question by unmarshalling something like `{"name":"evan","age":26}` because the last paragraph of your question isn't very specific. From that quote, it sounds like you need to implement `UnmarshalJSON` for your type. To be clear, you want to do this in Go; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818386/how-to-serialize-as-json-an-object-structure-with-circular-references

Comment: Marshal a type which implements json.Marshaler by bringing its own MarshalJSON method and errors always. Dead simple. Absolutely no input(s) used.

Comment: Yes, thanks @Volker -- that's what I should have done. #facepalm

Comment: Not sure why this hase been downvotes... @Volker - I'd gladly mark your comment as the accepted answer.

Comment: @JimB - I'm not unmarshalling raw json into a structure. I'm marshalling a structure to json and handling the potential error.

Comment: Yes sorry, completely misread.

Comment: To answer directly your question, if you pass channels or functions to the Marshal function you'll get a json.UnsupportedTypeError and if you pass a struct with a type that has value math.Inf or math.NaN you'll get a json.UnsupportedValueError

Comment: Oh, if only you had submitted your comment as an actual answer @hbejgel...

Answer (score 65):

Just to complement Jonathan's answer, the json.Marshal function can return two types of errors: `UnsupportedTypeError` or `UnsupportedValueError`

The first one can be caused, as Jonathan said by trying to Marshal an invalid type:

```
_, err := json.Marshal(make(chan int))
_, ok := err.(*json.UnsupportedTypeError) // ok == true
```

On the other hand you can also have the Marshal function return an error by passing an invalid value:

```
_, err := json.Marshal(math.Inf(1))
_, ok := err.(*json.UnsupportedValueError) // ok == true
```

Comment: Could this then be interpreted as "as long as the type doesn't change" the `err` can safely be ignored?

Answer (score 41):

**Update: now using a channel instead of a map[int]int to elicit the error**

---

Go-specific structures,e.g. `func` or `chan` refuse to serialize:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    value := make(chan int)
    _, err := json.Marshal(value)
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Read the source code you can found such a function to judge a encoder if not exist will return marshal error: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/encoding/json/encode.go

```golang
func newTypeEncoder(t reflect.Type, allowAddr bool) encoderFunc {
    // ignored
    switch t.Kind() {
    case reflect.Bool:
        return boolEncoder
    case reflect.Int, reflect.Int8, reflect.Int16, reflect.Int32, reflect.Int64:
        return intEncoder
    case reflect.Uint, reflect.Uint8, reflect.Uint16, reflect.Uint32, reflect.Uint64, reflect.Uintptr:
        return uintEncoder
    case reflect.Float32:
        return float32Encoder
    case reflect.Float64:
        return float64Encoder
    case reflect.String:
        return stringEncoder
    case reflect.Interface:
        return interfaceEncoder
    case reflect.Struct:
        return newStructEncoder(t)
    case reflect.Map:
        return newMapEncoder(t)
    case reflect.Slice:
        return newSliceEncoder(t)
    case reflect.Array:
        return newArrayEncoder(t)
    case reflect.Ptr:
        return newPtrEncoder(t)
    default:
        return unsupportedTypeEncoder
    }
}
```

We can find all kinds enum
at https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/reflect/type.go

So it's not hard to see that kinds not in above function are unable to marshal:

```
UnsafePointer,Complex64,Complex128,Chan,Func
```

Examples:

```golang
        json.Marshal(unsafe.Pointer(nil)) // UnsafePointer
        json.Marshal(complex64(1))        // Complex64
        json.Marshal(complex128(1))       // Complex128
        json.Marshal(make(chan struct{})) // Chan
        json.Marshal(func() {})           // Func
```

Answer (score 3):

https://go.dev/play/p/_Z29viT82CR.

Check this out -

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct {
    Id      int64  `json:"id"`
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    Persons []Person
}

func main() {
    f := Person{Id: 1, Name: "shriprasad"}
    f.Persons = append(f.Persons, f)

    result, err := json.Marshal(f)
    fmt.Println("error " + err.Error())
    fmt.Println(string(result))

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I was solving a problem of serializing/deserializing cyclic references in golang, and all the links go to this question. However, it's slightly misleading as the question is broader.

If you got into the same situation like me, and can't find a solution on how to deal with cyclic references, you can now use [tahwil](https://github.com/go-extras/tahwil) - a new library that I published on github. To my knowledge it's now the only library that facilitates serialization/deserialization of cyclic data structures in a generic way.

[Readme](https://github.com/go-extras/tahwil/blob/master/README.md) gives the information on how to use the library, so I will only duplicate the examples here.

#### Encoding:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/go-extras/tahwil"
)

type Person struct {
    Name     string
    Parent   *Person
    Children []*Person
}

func main() {
    parent := &Person{
        Name: "Arthur",
        Children: []*Person{
            {
                Name: "Ford",
            },
            {
                Name: "Trillian",
            },
        },
    }
    parent.Children[0].Parent = parent
    parent.Children[1].Parent = parent
    v, err := tahwil.ToValue(parent)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    res, err := json.Marshal(v)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(res))
}
```

#### Decoding:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/go-extras/tahwil"
)

type Person struct {
    Name     string    `json:"name"`
    Parent   *Person   `json:"parent"`
    Children []*Person `json:"children"`
}

func prepareData() []byte {
    parent := &Person{
        Name: "Arthur",
        Children: []*Person{
            {
                Name: "Ford",
            },
            {
                Name: "Trillian",
            },
        },
    }
    parent.Children[0].Parent = parent
    parent.Children[1].Parent = parent
    v, err := tahwil.ToValue(parent)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    res, err := json.Marshal(v)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return res
}

func main() {
    data := &tahwil.Value{}
    res := prepareData()
    err := json.Unmarshal(res, data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    person := &Person{}
    err = tahwil.FromValue(data, person)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf(`Name: %s
Children:
    - %s
    -- parent name: %s
    - %s
    -- parent name: %s
`, person.Name,
        person.Children[0].Name,
        person.Children[0].Parent.Name,
        person.Children[1].Name,
        person.Children[1].Parent.Name)
}
```

The main idea is to transform the original data to `tahwil.Value{}`, which essentially adds `refid`'s to all of your fields. Whenever `tahwil` encounters a cyclic reference, it replaces the actual object with a reference. And after that the graph is technically not cyclic anymore and thus can be marshalled to json.

Restoring the data means a reverse operation, i.e. any reference will be replaced by a pointer to an object.

P.S. Why `tahwil`? I tried to find some uncommon word for the name, and found an Arabic word (تحويل) that means *conversion*.